# Why does cancelling a pthread in an IO function of istream / ostream set the badbit?

Tags: c++, pthreads, iostream, libstdc++, cancellation

I was looking into libstdc++ code and was surprised that [it sets the badbit on a stream](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/libstdc++/api/a00971_source.html#l01047) when an `operator>>` or `operator<<` is interupted by a cancellation point of `pthread` (which, if I understand correctly, is implemented by throwing a special magic exception object).

Apparently, the C++ Standard requires that an exception escaping to the respective I/O function shall set the badbit. But to my understanding, a pthread cancellation isn't needed to be considered an "exception" in the C++ sense.

Does that mean that when calling `pthread_cancel`'ing a thread that uses `cout` and friends, one always has to clear the badbit after the thread doing the I/O exited (to be sure just in case the thread caused the badbit to be set)?

Comment: Terminating a thread is usually considered a bad idea in any case.

Comment: How would you use the stream after such a cancellation has occurred during a stream extraction? Another thread doesn't (may not) know how many characters have been extracted, or if/that there are any "leftovers" from the cancelled extraction. Similarly, for insertion, the stream cannot guarantee that the inserted data is in a valid state.

Comment: @DeadMG I agree, and I don't do that. But we shouldn't make the bad things worse, especially if it causes us to do more. So there must be a reason libstdc++ does it this way, it seems.

Comment: @dyp if it's an output stream, the stream should be perfectly usable afterwards in a different thread (the other thread could have done merely debug output for example). I would think there needs to be a good reason for setting the badbit here (since not doing it wouldn't seem to hurt anyone), so I'm interested in know this reason.

Comment: The stream object might be usable, but I think the source/sink might not be in a valid state. E.g. for an extraction, a sink with the data `name1 name2` and every extraction extracts a string until a whitespace is hit. Some thread consumes `nam`, is cancelled and leaves the source in the state `e1 name2`, then a second thread starts to consume a string but gets `e1`.

Comment: @dyp i see. well, the other thread could just always ignore all characters till the next newline or something. anyway, i'm still really interested whether i should be prepared to see streams suddenly break in programs using pthread cancellation (and is this perhaps specified somewhere?).

Comment: The underlying problem is that the other thread might not be able to detect that there are leftovers. It's simple here since the whitespace typically is consumed *at the beginning* of an operation, not at the end of it. The question whether or not you should be prepared is still valid, though, but maybe it's broader than just *streams*: cancelling a thread can lead to all kinds of invalid states, since not all functions can provide the strong exception guarantee (stream extraction is one example). Doesn't `operator>>` typically lead to calling a function that's a cancellation point?

Comment: @dyp yes, `read` and `write` are. see `man 7 pthread`

Comment: That's where I got the idea from ;) but I couldn't verify that `operator>>` e.g. for `cout` actually calls one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't specify any specific behavior for pthread's special exception. However, it specifies that catching any exception results in setting `std::ios_base::badbit`. The standard would need to be augmented to handle special exceptions special. The interactions between different standards doing things independent from the C++ in the C++ standard are clearly outside the C++ standard.

At one Kona meeting (~2006/2007) cancelling threads via exceptions was discussed at length. It was determined that supporting thread cancellation causes weird problem and that there were too many questions open to support thread cancellation in C++. If you want working thread cancallation support in C++ you'll need to get it integrated with the C++ standard. I wouldn't expect large support for thread cancellation in C++, though.

For more practical matters I can also imagine that throwing from, e.g., `read(2)` may leave the stream of an unsuspecting I/O stream implementation in an inconsistent state! System functions didn't use to throw. If the start doing so funny things may happen. That is, the stabdard library would need to be aware of this change to the system call behavior. This silent change in behavior was one of the arguments why thread cancellation via exceptions wasn't considered a viable approach: what applies to the standard C++ library implentation applies even more to user code.

Comment: thanks, that seems to support the view that things are just broken. I will take care no part of C++ code I use makes use of cancellation!